# Training tensorflow model with multiple common output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a Tensorflow model with multiple same outputs. A recurrent neural network predicts labels for an image for t iterative timesteps. Each timestep is supposed to predict the image class, and deeper timesteps are expected to improve the performance. You could simply imagine a deep model with intermediate outputs that are expected to predict one common task. All the output is compared with the same label.

The problem is that there are too much outputs. All the outputs are successfully compiled, but I don't think my approach of feeding a tiled data to the model isn't the optimal solution for my problem. How could I improve this in terms of memory, clean code?

```
CHO_RNN=CustomLayers.RNN_Decoder(units,...)
prediction_list=[]

for x in range(settings['refinement_t']):
  pred, hidden = CHO_RNN(features, hidden)
  prediction_list.append(pred)

model=tf.keras.models.Model(input_image, prediction_list)
...

data={'output1':labels,'output2':labels,'output3':labels,...'output15':labels}
model.fit(x=images,y=data,...)
```

Edit:
One more reason I want to achieve this is because at inference, the model output is very complex, and functions for evaluation ex) model.evaluate doesn't work well. Also, the verbose print and tensorboard plot is extremely long.

Edit2: RNN decoder code

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, features, hidden):
    # features(CNN_encoder output) shape == (batch_size, 36, embedding_dim)

    # hidden shape == (batch_size, hidden_size)
    # hidden_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden_size)
    hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)

    # attention_hidden_layer shape == (batch_size, 36, units)
    attention_hidden_layer = (tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) +
                                         self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis)))

    # score shape == (batch_size, 36, 1)
    # This gives you an unnormalized score for each image feature.
    score = self.V(attention_hidden_layer)

    # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, 36, 1)
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

    # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
    context_vector = attention_weights * features
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

    return context_vector, attention_weights

class RNN_Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units, class_types):
        #units: # classes
        super(RNN_Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.units,
                                        return_sequences=True,
                                        return_state=True,
                                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(class_types)

        self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.units)

    def call(self, features, hidden):
        # hidden: previous states   features: feature map(conv output)
        # defining attention as a separate model

        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(features, hidden)

            # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
        output, state = self.gru(x)

        # shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        x = self.fc1(output)

        # x shape == (batch_size * max_length, hidden_size)
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))

        # output shape == (batch_size * max_length, class_types)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x, state, attention_weights
```

Edit 3:
I managed to solve this partly by defining a custom loss function, therefore the model still outputs very many vectors, but it can be trained without tiling the data.

Comment: Can you share more details about your model as well as the tiling you've used. There are ways to reduce memory consumption at the cost of longer training time, but to give an answer i'd need more details about your current approach

Comment: @thushv89 Thaank you for your interest. The code I posted is the complete code defining the class probability prediction part after the feature extractor. I would like to say my convolutional feature extractor is a very conventional VGG style CNN, thus seems unnecessary. The output of the feature extractor is `(6,6,512)` and is reshaped to `(36,512)` I posted the RNN_Decoder and attention code.